# docker веб сервер в контейнере преимущества

Tags: nginx, docker, веб-сервер, php-nginx

Есть ли преимущества развертывания веб сервера(nginx+php+db) в контейнере(docker) для хостинга сайтов перед стандартным использованием выделенного сервера? Какие в этом могут быть плюсы и минусы?

Comment: Ну хотя бы один из основных, что докер ты один раз помучался, настроил и потом если захочешь еще раз где-то это реализовать, то уже не надо париться - взял поставил докер и запустил свой код.

Comment: Докер очень удобен для переноса сайта с сервера на сервер. На тестовом сервере настроил все базы данных, конфиги, зависимости, приложения, затем экспортировал контейнер и на продакшене импортировал. Не нужно маяться с настройкой среды, когда вдруг выясняется, что на продакшене какая-то не та версия библиотеки, от чего шайтан-арба не взлетает. В контейнере всё настроено и работает.

Comment: Непонятно, почему тут противопоставляется использование докера использованию выделенного сервера. Докер - это средство упаковки и изоляции приложений. Если используется выделенный сервер на линукс, то использование докера или аналогичного инструмента на нем жизненно необходимо.

Comment: всем спасибо за ответы